# Specifying Windows SDK in project, props, directory.build.target, command-line... what is the order of precedence?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

1. Many of our C++ vcxproj files specify an exact Windows SDK version when people have set it over the years... messy.
2. To combat this we created `Company.props` file which specifies the preferred version, that in theory is added to every project... except those it's not.
3. I discovered you can put settings in [directory.build.props/.target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019). So we added one to replicate Company.props for all the projects that missed the above, on our build machine (I don't think this is used when building within VS).
4. You can also pass an argument to msbuild.exe `/p:WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=10.0.18362.0` so this is set in our Azure DevOps build steps.

I *think* this is the order of precedence e.g. 2 overrides 1, 4 overrides 1,2 & 3 - is this correct?
I don't want to specify it in more places than needed because it's more opportunity for them to get out of sync!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this is the order of precedence e.g. 2 overrides 1, 4 overrides 1,2 &3 – is this correct?

**Yes**, correct.

Actually, the 3 -> `Directory.Build.props` file is an update of normal `.props` file. `Directory.Build.props` avoids manually adding a customized `.props` file to every project files in the solution. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) it explains.

So 2 & 3 should be the very similar things. And 3 better than 2.

For 4, just as what you mentioned, 4 overrides 1,2&3. As it uses the “command”, the command makes the used properties which are needed to be reassigned more directly to run.

Did a small test on my side.(without using DevOps, and tested locally but it should be the same)

I created a simple normal C++ console project just for test, and set the WindowsTargetPlatformVersion = 10.0.**19041**.0 in project’s property page.

[image]

Created two files, one named `Directory.Build.props` and the other named `MyProps.props`.(For the reason why create a `MyProps.props`file, refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#customize-c-builds))

In `Directory.Build.props` file, added following codes:

```
<Project>
   <PropertyGroup>
       <ForceImportAfterCppProps>$(MsbuildThisFileDirectory)\MyProps.props
       </ForceImportAfterCppProps>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In `MyProps.props` file, added following codes:

```
<Project>
   <PropertyGroup>
      <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17763.0
      </WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Saved them to the project folder.

**Test 1**

Directly built this project in VS, and the build results/detailed output showed the `WindowsTargetPlatformVersion` reassigned to "10.0.17763.0" and it also showed the previous value = "10.0.19041.0".

[image]

**Test 2**

Launched `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019` and ran this MSBuild command:

```
msbuild myproject.sln /p:WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=10.0.18362.0 -detailedSummary -fileLogger
```

[image]

Build successfully and generated a log file(msbuild.log) which logged Build output. In this log file, you can see that the `10.0.18362.0` logged and was related to `Property reassignment`.

[image]

Of course, I also saw this message `The "WindowsTargetPlatformVersion" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.`, so I'm not sure, but perhaps there may be something wrong with changing `WindowsTargetPlatformVersion` properties by setting and using it in MSBuild command line, and it should be another issue/question.

**Summary**

If "WindowsTargetPlatformVersion" property can be changed/set in MSBuild command line(I didn't test more conditions or test other properties), then 4 overrides 1,2 & 3.